# Why is resize implemented the way it is?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, resize

I have several questions about rebuilding `HashMaps` when adding new key-values pair. I will ask questions based on these facts (they are true for Oracle JVM, not sure if they are correct for  other JVMs):

1. Resize rebuilds `HashMap` to have a bigger inner table array every time when you grow HashMap bigger than threshold (threshold = loadFactor*numberOfEntries). It does not matter in which bucket the newly created Entry is put - Map will still grow bigger. Even if all of the Entries go into one bucket (i.e. their keys' `hashCode()` return the same number).
2. `HashMap` does not shrink when data is removed. Even if all keys are removed from `HashMap`, the inner size of it's table does not change.

Now the questions:

1. Are these facts correct?

If they are, then:

2. Why resize implemented this way? Is it the intention to grow the inner table even when it is obviously not necessary? Or a bug?
3. Why it does not shrink?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, these facts are correct.

1. *Detecting* whether it is "obviously not necessary" would take a lot of time, and it's almost always redundant, since the case where all the keys have the same hash code is rare.  In short, you're paying a significant expense (tracking how common one particular hash code is) for *everybody* just to save some work in an extremely rare case, which will end up costing more than it saves.
2. Because removing is a somewhat less common operation, and it's usually followed by refilling the map.  If you want to start the map over with a smaller table, you can just assign it to a `new HashMap` and let the old one be garbage-collected.

Comment: Wow, that is reasonable, thanks! Can I ask one more? Why can't we grow hashmap when table buckets are added but not when entries are added?

Comment: That question doesn't make sense.  "Table buckets are added" is a synonym for "the hashmap growing."  There's no way for a user of the hash map to "add table buckets"; table buckets are added when there are more entries.

Comment: sorry, by "table buckets are added" I meant "the inner table array is filled". I mean, why don't we resize the map when all table array elements are not null (or a fraction of them)?

Comment: By resizing when entries are added, we're essentially resizing the table when the _average number of entries per bucket_ exceeds a certain amount.  What happens in practice is that each bucket in the original table is split into two buckets in the new table, with (on average) half in one new bucket and half in the other.  It's not really relevant how many buckets are nonempty, so much as the average number of entries per bucket.