# Why does hashmap does not have ensureCapacity() method like ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, hash, hashmap

`ArrayList` and `HashMap` both have constructors to set initial capacity yet `ArrayList` provides `ensureCapacity()` to ensure that internal array is already increased if some good amount of elements are expected to be inserted. Same can happen with a `HashMap` too in some situation. Then why does `HashMap` not have an ensure capacity method that will already keep the buckets ready?

Comment: Are you asking why the designers of `HashMap` decided to go with `initialCapacity` and `loadFactor` instead?

Comment: Mostly that messing with those details in the first place is a bad sign.

Comment: Because it doesn't need one. You don't have to resize a `HashMap` when it exceeds its capacity, but you do have to rehash it when you add another bucket.

Comment: Given the existing implementation of hashmap (initialcapacity, loadfactor/threshold), what could have gone wrong if the developers added an ensureCapacity() method too? That is what I am trying to find out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is resize implemented the way it is?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290155/why-is-resize-implemented-the-way-it-is)

Comment: What would have gone right? Given the existing implementation, what would it do exactly?

Comment: ArrayLIst has ensurecapacity, what does it do exactly? Increase the array size right? So that it does not have to be increased at the time when data load is coming. Why not for hashmap? An ensureCapacity() method could have kept the Entries table already created and rehashing already done for existing elements?

Comment: You haven't answered my question. `HashMap` already works, so what would have been gained by adding an `ensureCapacity()` method? Yes, it increases the array size in `ArrayList`, but *at* the time more data is being added actually. 'Why not for `HashMap`' is because a `HashMap`  doesn't have an array that has to be increased when new data comes in. It *is* increased, but in response to the load factor going too high, not just in response to a capacity violation. So calling the method that does that `ensureCapacity()` instead of `resize()` would be misleading. Duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, it's not very useful.

Structures like `ArrayList` and `HashMap` have a concept of *capacity*, which is the length of some internal array that isn't directly visible to users. The capacity is distinct from the *size*, which is the number of elements or entries logically contained in the structure.

The word "capacity" is really a misnomer, as it doesn't actually represent any limit that's significant to users. It's an implementation detail. As elements or entries are added, internal arrays will be resized automatically and transparently. There are no semantics to changing the capacity. You can't tell whether a call to `ensureCapacity()` has actually changed the capacity, and if it did change the capacity, the list or map is still equal to anything it was equal to before.

The reason for having the notion of capacity at all in the API is to improve performance in the cases where the user knows that a lot of elements are going to be added. This helps avoid the overhead of repeated resizing, in cases where the user knows that a lot of elements are going to be added. The most common case for this is at construction time, where it's most likely that you'll know how many elements you're going to add.

Note that the batch addition methods (`addAll` or `putAll`) will look at the size of what's about to be added, and do any necessary resizing of the destination once.

You'd call `Arraylist.ensureCapacity()` if you have an existing list that you want to add lot of elements to; you have a good idea of how many are going to be added; you have to add them one at a time, instead of in a batch; and your application is so performance-sensitive that you have to avoid multiple resizing. This seems pretty rare.

One could imagine an API `HashMap.ensureCapacity()`. If necessary, it would resize the internal table, and then rehash all the elements into the buckets of this table. This would help avoid repeated resizes/rehashes if a lot of entries were added in the future. This is a semantically a reasonable thing to do, but the number of cases where it's really useful seems quite small.

The bottom line is that `HashMap.ensureCapacity()` could be added, but there's little enough use for it that it's never been a priority to add it.

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` is fundamentally different to `ArrayList`.

The number of 'buckets' in an `ArrayList` is just the size of the backing array, when it's full, it's full.

The number of 'buckets' in a `HashMap` is not really a good indication of how many objects it can store, given that multiple objects can hash to the same bucket, and the collision resolution strategy that Java employs is chaining (i.e. creating a linked list, or similar, for the bucket if multiple objects hash there). (citation required!)

Ensuring the number of buckets in a `HashMap` doesn't ensure that you will fill them all before you've already reached a load factor that reduces your performance intolerably. So load factor is a better way to ensure that you have the performance you want.

Comment: Matt, no matter the elements are going in the same bucket or not, hashmap still will resize and rehash when load factor/threshold is hit.

Comment: @Puneet Exactly. *Not* when the capacity is hit.