# Why ArrayList has no capacity() method, but has ensureCapacity(int), while Vector, StringBuffer, StringBuilder have both?

Tags: java, arraylist, capacity

To remember JCF class methods I am always trying to find some logic for memorizing thru understanding.

Besides List interface methods, **ArrayList class has capacity() method, but does not have ensureCapacity(int) method. While Vector, StringBuffer, StringBuilder have both.**

There could have been following logic: **capacity() method always present if we also have ensureCapacity(int) method**, because it allows to change capacity in runtime (also overriding capacity given to constructor), so we may be interested in currently set capacity.

But ArrayList breaks this logic: it has capacity(), but has no ensureCapacity(int). While almost all other classes with capacity () (Vector, StringBuffer, StringBuilder) have both.

Is there any logic / practical reason behind ArrayList being exception of above (mnemonic) "rule", or it is just a historical/compatibility quirk?

P.S. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41995694/why-does-hashmap-does-not-have-ensurecapacity-method-like-arraylist) relates remotely to my question. It states, that HashMap might have had ensureCapacity(int), like ArrayList, but it does not have it because designers think it is rarely needed.

Comment: Your title says "ArrayList has no capacity() method", but your post says "ArrayList class has capacoty() method"...

Comment: Your basis is incorrect - ArrayList does not have a capacity() method, and does have an ensureCapacity(int) method

Answer (score 0):

**Why ArrayList doesn't have capacity()**

*ArrayList* in Java is kind of a cross between an array and a *List* - hence why it's named the way it is. The [JavaDoc here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) states that it's a

> [r]esizable-array implementation of the List interface

Therefore, it doesn't have any *capacity*, which implies a **maximum** amount it can hold. Instead, it just has a number of items in it at any *given time*, given by

```
ArrayList.size()
```

The **ensureCapacity(int)** method is just a helper method that can be used to make sure the instance has at least **x** number of elements - the same as checking **size() > x**.

**Thinking about relationships**

You mention the classes *ArrayList, Vector, StringBuffer* and *StringBuilder*. You're talking about two distinct types of objects, here: two things that are **collections**, and two things that are **character sequences**. *ArrayList* and *Vector* both extend *AbstractList*, while *StringBuffer* and *StringBuilder* don't extend anything (aside from *Object*) but rather implement *CharacterSequence*. The fact that these two parents have some method names in common is a coincidence in your choosing of classes, but intentional in terms of naming - those methods have the same behavior among these classes.

You shouldn't be thinking *ArrayList* is related to *StringBuffer*, or *Vector* to *StringBuilder*, because they aren't - they're completely different inheritance trees.